# Canon All in One MX520 scanner issue

Tags: scanning, canon-pixma

My Canon MX520 scanner is taking a very long time to scan, the speed is averaging between 9 - 20minutes to scan 1 simple document. I need some ideas to how to make it operate faster.

Comment: How is it connected to your computer (via USB)? What resolution are you scanning at? What software are you using to scan? Have you tried connecting it with a different cable? Is printing at normal speed? Can you connect it to another computer to test scanning? What is the physical action during the scanning time (scan head moves in tiny increments the whole time, the actual scan head motion is fast but then it takes forever for the image to show up, it scans in small increments with backtracking in between)? Are you initiating the scan from the printer or computer? What is the output format?

Comment: It's wirelessly connected to the computer through wifi. Printing is great and very fast. I could connect it to another computer. When scanning the scanner will move about every 3-4 minutes then very fast right when it ends. Most of the time it times out before the scan is complete. I'm scanning at 300 I thought by decreasing it to 150 would be the cure but no luck. I have tried initiating the scan from the computer and the printer and it has the same issue.

Comment: A wild guess is that it's a communication problem.  Try connecting it via USB, even if just to test whether the problem disappears.  BTW, you will probably need to load the driver before connecting the USB cable (it will typically tell you when to connect).

Comment: I don't have the USB cable anymore, do you connect it to the front of the machine or to the back of the machine. I tried re-installing the drivers and using the software disk. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: USB cables are cheap and widely available.  You might even be able to borrow one from another device for testing.  If front vs. back refers to your computer, any one should work.  Your symptoms sound like a WiFi problem.

Comment: I managed to find the cable for the scanner. I did a test and it scanned in 4 minutes, now I disconnected the cable and I'm timing the wireless scan

Comment: Just curious what is the length of time it usually should take to scan a document with an all in one printer?

Comment: For some reason the scan using wifi was 1minute less, which is a lot better than it used to be at 20 even 9minutes what quite long.

Comment: Typically a fraction of a minute.  If it's taking 4 minutes with a wired connection, something's wrong.

Comment: I didn't see any pop up about downloading drivers. Perhaps I didn't download the correct driver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41994/discussion-between-fixer1234-and-user554246).